# Difference between secure function evaluation and private function evaluation?

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

Yao's garbled circuit is used to compute multiparty computation. I know that secure function evaluation is used to hide users input and circuit from each other.

Can any body tell me what is private function evaluation? and how is it different from secure function evaluation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will find similar terminology interchanged a lot in this field. So, secure multiparty computation can take the acronym MPC, SFE, SMC and so on. In general, you should look at each paper closely to see what they mean in their definition. However, pretty much secure function evaluation is just another term for secure computation. In contrast private function evaluation *can* refer to the case where the function itself is private and is not revealed. Note that these are completely orthogonal to the number of parties involved.